# Import-Excel only data without header in string - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have installed Import-Excel Module for PowerShell [by dfinke](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) which has a great functionality but I'm facing some troubles with the headers.
I would like to insert only the text into a string array, but instead, it comes with the header even when -NoHeader is declared. According to the documentation it's not its function not insert the header in the variable but I'm looking for a way to do it. So far I came with a newbie solution of `$xlsxArray | Format-Table -HideHeaders | Out-File C:\temp\info.txt` and then remove the spaces with .Trim() so the file doesn't get written *@{P1=ContentofTheCell}*.
Is there a better way to accomplish it?
Thank you so far.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a listing of the columns, and an example of what the expected output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give enough detail about the desired output, but I'll try to give guidance.

`Import-Excel` will return objects.  Normally the column headers become the property names on the objects.  When you use `-NoHeader`, the property names are simply named P1, P2 etc...  An object's properties must have names. If you want the data from those properties you may have to process differently.  You can access the properties like any other object collection:

```
$ExcelData = Import-Excel "C:\Temp\Some.xlsx"
$ExcelData.PropertyName
```

The PropertyName would be the column header from the file.  So let's say I had a colum named Balance in that file, then the example would something like:

```
$ExcelData = Import-Excel "C:\Temp\Some.xlsx"
$ExcelData.balance
```

Output:

```
7254.74
4268.16
3051.32
64.77
323.22
146.62
14798.83
```

Note: these are pretty simple examples.  Obviously things can get more complex.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, but this was exactly what I wanted. Have access to the data then be able to write them to txt file without the headers. It's was more a powershell question than the module itself. Thank you, appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: If someone ever need: I inserted only the info directly into the array with = `$S3 = (Import-Excel $sheet -WorksheetName 'S3' -StartColumn 1 -EndColumn 1 -StartRow 2 -NoHeader).P1`